# how to get the count of number of values in a column?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table called `tbl_company`. It has the fields

```
id  comp_name     followers
 1    abc         15,23,88,99
 2    bbc         1,10,66
```

In followers field i am saving the employees id of those who are following that company. This works fine. In code behind, each company page, I want to display how many followers have them

example  in  `abc company` page i want show

No of people following is  `4`

example  in  `bbc company` page i want show

No of people following is  `3`

like this i want to display.how i can get this count.....

Thanks

Comment: When asking questions, please take the time and effort to spell words correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's `TSQL` version,

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Comp_name, 
        CASE WHEN LEN(followers) > 0
             THEN (LEN(followers) - LEN(REPLACE(followers, ',', '')) + 1)
             ELSE 0
        END as FollowerCount 
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/536a9/3)

In `MySQL`

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Comp_name, 
        CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(followers) > 0
             THEN (CHAR_LENGTH(followers) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(followers, ',', '')) + 1)
             ELSE 0
        END as FollowerCount 
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d50b/1)

Comment: sir as per above i written querySELECT  Id, 
        company, 
        CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(followers) > 0
             THEN (CHAR_LENGTH(followers) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(followers, ',', '')) + 1)
             ELSE 0
        END as FollowerCount 
FROM    company_followers,  but its showing the following error.i am using sql server 2008 erroro message is   Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'CHAR_LENGTH' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Microsoft sqlserver 2008 error message is Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'CHAR_LENGTH' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: because the query you are executing is for `MySQL`. here is for `SQL Server`, `SELECT  Id, 
  company, 
  CASE  WHEN LEN(followers) > 0 
    THEN (LEN(followers) - LEN(REPLACE(followers, ',', '')) + 1) 
    ELSE 0 
  END as FollowerCount 
FROM  company_followers`

Answer (score 7):

Comma-separated lists in a database field are unwieldy and in general a really bad idea. The main reason being it completely nullifies the reason to use a relational database in the first place (e.g. indexes, foreign keys, and joins).

You should normalize your database so you instead have:

```
tbl_company
--------------
id   comp_name
1    abc
2    bbc
```

```
company_followers
----------------------
company_id follower_id
1          15
1          23
1          88
1          99
2           1
2          10
2          66
```

Then you can simply execute the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM company_followers
WHERE company_id = @company_id
```

---

If you're absolutely stuck with this schema, you should first complain to whoever wrote it if possible <g>, then the simplest solution is to return the whole darn string and count the commas in C# (and add 1 of course).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good database design. You must think twice using this sort of table structure. This can be further normalized. If you don't properly do this at the beginning it could cause problems later and is not expandable. So, it would be better if you could change the table structure.

The data will look like the following with new table structure.

company table:

```
id     comp_name
1      abc
2      bbc
```

company_follower table:

```
company_id     follower
1              15
1              23
1              88
1              99
2              1
2              10
2              66
```

Then your query for your result is,

```
SELECT COUNT(company_id)
  FROM company_follower
  WHERE company_id = @company_id;
```

Comment: If you need to keep to this design, @JW. has given the solution. Yet, I prefer move to new design at this stage even. It's not a big problem though you already have even several thousands rows inserted. You can write a _sql statement_ to move those data to new table. This is just a minor problem occurred from your bad database design. You will have `update` `delete` problems and expandability issues. So, changing the database structure is the best remedy. Refer [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/). That explains it.