# SQL loop in select

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

Need to update a column in our database. A column which can have upto 7 sets of numbers separated by a space between them.
like

```
3548 132 760 2348
123 346
37 982 439
```

I need to update these columns like the following.

```
3548 132 760 2348 0 0 0 
123 346 0 0 0 0 0
37 982 439 0 0 0
```

i.e like something to full fill the 7 sets of the number. change the 4 sets to 7 sets.

I could able to count the number of sets in the column by the following

```
SELECT LENGTH('3548 132 760 2348')-LENGTH(REPLACE('3548 132 760 2348', ' ', '')) + 1
```

Which returns the number of sets in the column.
What SQL query will help to update or return the value as given above.

Comment: As @Devart suggests you should think of changing the design to further normalize it. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060529/how-to-get-the-count-of-number-of-values-in-a-column) will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query -

```
SET @str = '548 132 760 2348';
SELECT RPAD(@str, LENGTH(@str) + (6 - (LENGTH(@str) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@str, ' ', '')))) * 2,' 0');

>548 132 760 2348 0 0 0
```

But if these are ID values, then I'd suggest you to normalize data.

Comment: your solution works fine in mysql. Thanks. By chance do you know how to do it for teradata?